# How to overwrite a row_number value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift, window-functions, row-number

How to overwrite a column in SQL (Redshift) ?

The following query gives me an error `Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate`

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET rank = temp.new_rank
FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY date) AS new_rank
      FROM table1
      ) temp;
```

Comment: I am using Redshift

Comment: What happens if you add a WHERE clause to tell the engine how to match a record in `table1` with its counterpart in `temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause that matches each row of the table with a row of the subquery:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET rank = t.new_rank
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY date) AS new_rank
  FROM table1
) AS t
WHERE t.session_id = t1.session_id AND t.date = t1.date;
```

I use the columns `session_id` and `date` in the `WHERE` clause, but if there is another column, like a unique id or any other primary key it would be better to use that.